# Which features/classes are implemented in android sample projects

Tags: android, sample

Is there a feature/classes implemented list for the android samples that come with the SDK?

http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html

E.g. If I am reading up about AdapterView, and want to find out which sample project(s) use this AdapterView class - how do I find this quickly? I see that in the samples website on developer.android.com , the samples are only described as Name / Description Text , but not with features/classes implemented.

Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I am reading up about AdapterView, and want to find out which sample project(s) use this AdapterView class - how do I find this quickly?

If you are using Chrome or Chromium for a Web browser, install the [Android SDK Samples Search extension](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sdk-samples-search). This will add a "(sample code)" link after the big bold class name at the top of each class' JavaDocs page. That link will then conduct a search on GitHub for references to that class in:

- the [Android SDK's samples](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples)
- [the sample projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus) from [my book](http://commonsware.com/Android)

That's the easiest way that I know of to find sample code that specifically references certain classes.

Note, though, that this is a fairly simplistic search. Notably, it does not search up and down class hierarchies. So, the search will find samples that refer to `AdapterView`, but not `ListView` -- you would need to go to the `ListView` JavaDocs page and use its sample-code link to find `ListView` references.

This extension also works nicely with the [Android SDK Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-sdk-search/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin) extension, which:

- Adds an `ad` search to the "omnibox" (a.k.a., address/search bar in Chrome), so `ad AdapterView` would take you right to the `AdapterView` documentation
- Adds a "(view source)" link to the JavaDocs for each class, next to the "(sample code)" link, that brings up the source code to that class